# setTag() getTag() integer issue

Tags: java, android, adapter

When getTag is used for String no errors and it run smoothly but if it use for int my app crashes. this happen when onclick is initiate. i want to get the id by setTag. see my code below.

MyAdpater

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contact current = data.get(position);
        holder.itemId.setText(String.valueOf(current.getId()));
        holder.title.setText(current.getName());
        holder.email.setText(current.getEmail());
        holder.itemId.setTag(holder);
        holder.title.setTag(holder);
        holder.email.setTag(holder);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView title;
        public TextView email;
        public TextView itemId;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextName);
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextUname);
            itemId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextId);
            title.setOnClickListener(this);
            email.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) v.getTag();
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            Contact contact = data.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(context, contact.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. I forgot to convert it to `String` before calling.

```
String new = String.valueOf(contact.getId());
```

Solved!

Comment: Please set your own answer as the correct one, then.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to get it by getTag method.**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView title;
        public TextView email;
        public TextView itemId;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextName);
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextUname);
            itemId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextId);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Contact rowContactClicked = (Contact) v.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(rowContactClicked.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

you should remember getTag return the Object stored in this view as a tag